# Search for a field in all objects

Tags: soql, custom-field, query, standard-objects

I am looking for a field named "Owner_c" in all Objects.
Any easy way to find it through work bench or a query in Developer Console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOQL/SOSL won't help you here. You can, however, write a query using the Tooling API like this:

```
SELECT Id,TableEnumOrId FROM CustomField WHERE DeveloperName = 'Owner'
```

The easiest way to do this is to open the Developer Console, click the Query Editor tab, check the "Use Tooling API" checkbox, and type in the query. Note that you do *not* include the `__c` when querying this table.

For custom objects, you'll get a custom object ID. You can see the object by using the standard URL for an object:

```
https://<domain>.salesforce.com/01IC0000000XXXXXXX
```

[image: Tooling API query in Developer Console]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it using Force.com IDE or Mavensmate. Search in the metadata folder. There will be break down of all the fields by object level.

Steps for Mavensmate:

1. Open Project Folder>>Config
2. Open ".org_metadata" folder
3. Search for ".fields.Field_You_Are_Looking_For__c"

The usual structure for config definition is :

Account.fields.Field_You_Are_Looking_For__c,
Opportunity.fields.Field_You_Are_Looking_For__c,
Contact.fields.Field_You_Are_Looking_For__c

So ".fields.Field_You_Are_Looking_For__c" will get the Field_You_Are_Looking_For__c across all the objects.

There should be something very similar in Eclipse too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i wanted to try this solution but couldnt. somehow i have issue logging in using Mavensmate and Eclipse. it took me 6 hours to install and try both. EOD couldnt add the project.

Answer (score 0):

This cycle in debugger worked for me

```java
Map <String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for (Schema.SObjectType m1 : schemaMap.values()){
    String objName =  String.valueOf(m1);
    Schema.SObjectType s = (SObjectType) schemaMap.get(objName);
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> tfields = s.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for (Schema.SObjectField m2 : tfields.values()){
        String fieldName =  String.valueOf(m2);
        if(fieldName.equals('YOUR_FIELD')){
            System.debug(m1);
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query with the tooling api should give you the result you are looking for along with the object name.
Modify the where condition to include like and wild cards if you want to search for fields with similar names across objects

select id,CreatedDate,  DeveloperName,EntityDefinition.Label from CustomField where DeveloperName = 'Owner'

Comment: Quite the same as the accepted answer from 7 years ago, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, the only addition is the sobject name